# Equation of third side of Triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

A  Triangle is formed by Pair of lines 
$$ ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$$ and a third side L3.Given the Orthocentre of Triangle is $$(c,d)$$, Find Equation of Third Side.

Answer (score 1):

At first let's divide the pair of lines equation by $x^2$ and then solve the equation for $\frac{y}{x}$.
So we get the equations of both straight lines:
$$s_1:\quad y = m_1 x$$
and
$$s_2:\quad y = m_2 x,$$
where
$$m_1 = \frac{-h-\sqrt{h^2-ba}}{b}$$
and
$$m_2 = \frac{-h+\sqrt{h^2-ba}}{b}.$$
The equation of altitude $h_1$ which pass through the Orthocenter $(c,d)$ and is perpendicular to $s_1$ is given by the following equation:
$$h_1:\quad y-d= -\frac{1}{m_1}(x-c).$$
The coordinates of vertices $A$ and $B$ such that $\{A\}=s_2 \cap s_1$ and $\{B\}=s_2 \cap h_1$ are:
$$A=(0,0)$$
$$B=\left(\frac{dm_1+c}{m_1m_2+1}, \frac{dm_1m_2+cm_2}{m_1m_2+1}\right).$$
The equation of the third side is given by:
$$l_3:\quad y- \frac{dm_1m_2+cm_2}{m_1m_2+1}= - \frac{c}{d}\left(x-\frac{dm_1+c}{m_1m_2+1}\right)$$

Recall that:
$$m_1m_2=\frac{a}{b} \tag{1}$$
and
$$m_1+m_2=-\frac{2h}{b}. \tag{2}$$

Substituting $(1)$ and $(2)$ in $l_3$ equation we get:
$$l_3:\quad d(a+b)y+c(a+b)x=ad^2-2hcd+bc^2$$